# js how to check two objects values in an array are together

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

If I have the array:

```
let messages = [
  {
    username: 'john',
    message: 'hi'
  },
  {
    username: 'john',
    message: 'there'
  },
  {
    username: 'bob',
    message: 'hello'
  },
  {
    username: 'john',
    message: 'whats up'
  }
]
```

If i have messages like:
[image: Vuejs example]

In vuejs rendered out how would I combine messages with the same username and render the text under each other?

Comment: Well how are you doing that code above now?

Comment: I have a Message component that takes in a message prop and uses v-for from a  messages array to render it.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is like in discord where the messages from the same user doesn't get rendered with the username but gets added to each other.

Comment: So loop over the array, if the previous item is the same, push the content into that one. OR you change your looping to determine if the previous heading is the same, do not show it.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't to it in the view, use a `computed` to get the data you want. You can then use `<template>` tags to control which elements are shown, that way you don't need to wrap the elements into a single DOM element.

Below is an example that shows a straight forward way of generating an array for the `computed` that can then be iterated over.

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      messages: [{
          username: 'john',
          message: 'hi'
        },
        {
          username: 'john',
          message: 'there'
        },
        {
          username: 'bob',
          message: 'hello'
        },
        {
          username: 'john',
          message: 'whats up'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    byUser() {
      const arr = [];
      let tempName = null;
      let tempGroup = {}
      this.messages.forEach(m => {
        if (tempName !== m.username) {
          tempGroup = {
            username: m.username,
            messages: []
          }
          arr.push(tempGroup);
        }
        tempGroup.messages.push(m.message);
        tempName = m.username;
      })
      return arr;
    }
  }

}).mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="container">
  <template v-for="(m, i) in byUser">
    <h2>
      {{ m.username }}
    </h2>
    
    <p v-for="message in m.messages">
      {{ message }}
    </p>
    
    <hr>
  </template>
</div>
```